# Cannot correctly remove Lazarus, error exit status 2

Tags: apt, dpkg, uninstall

**I've tried to install Lazarus, but to no avail, so i tried to remove it.**

```
 installed lazarus-src-2.2 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: too many errors, stopping (<-- translated PL to EN)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lazarus-src-2.2
Processing has been stopped due to a occurance of too many errors (<-- translated PL to EN)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You may try reinstalling the problematic package and then remove as you tried before.

Comment: Nothing, the other packages don't even want to remove after i did this.

Answer (score 0):

The Lazarus package provided by Ubuntu repositories is generally for an older version. So, I normally install (or upgrade) Lazarus by downloading it from their web site.

To do this:

- First remove/purge any packages with names like `fpc...` and `lazarus...` from your system:

```
$ sudo apt purge fpc*
```

- Download the three `.deb` packages for the ***latest version*** from [SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20amd64%20DEB/) into a temporary location, say `/tmp`.
- Then, install first the `fpc...` packages using the commands:

```
$ sudo apt install /tmp/fpc-src_3.2.2-210709_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt install /tmp/fpc-laz_3.2.2-210709_amd64.deb
```

and finally the `lazarus...` package using the command:

```
$ sudo apt install /tmp/lazarus-project_2.2.4-0_amd64.deb
```